# interpretation of p value of pettitt test from trend package in R

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have applied pettitt.test function in R. I want to know whether my change point is significant or not. My p values are 0.22, 0.09,0.77 for three different time series.

Comment: For significance to achieve, the p-value should be below 0.05 but in you case, all p values are above it, so conclude that there is no significance.

Comment: when I checked with critical values of pettitt test my test statistic is coming greater than critical values for second time series at .05 significance level but p value is 0.09. In this case should I accept or reject the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

The p value of 0.09 greater than 0.05 suggests that Accept HO. I presume that you are not doing one tailed test. In that case there is significance. In case of two tailed test, the p=0.09 is not significant.

Comment: In the standard framework we never accept H0, we only fail to reject it.

Comment: Please merge your accounts.  It's easy: just follow the instructions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: In the documentation of pettitt.test function why it says approximation is good for p<=0.5

Answer (score 0):

Some software also use significance level to be at 10% level. Please check.

There is a comment that the standard phrase is fail to reject Ho. My understanding is that the Alpha is the probability of  rejecting  Ho when it is true. So if you fail to reject Ho means you are going with the decision that Ho is true. Any way let us not be too the technical. That way are you testing the assumptions , first and then going for the test?